# How to customise up navigation in android?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Instead of having up navigation in the action bar return to its parent activity, I would like to have it return to the last fragment or just be able to alter its behaviour and appearence.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you want the Up navigation button changed or just the back button on the device function changed?

Comment: I would like the up button changed in terms of appearence and functionality. @BR89

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: nothing that the up navigation is like any other menu item except it is special as far as the id is concerned:

Let me add a few more code to demo how to change icon:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

assert toolbar != null;
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.close);
```

Handling Fragments Popping:

```
//when adding your fragment to the activity, add it to back stack like this
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("frag1");

//inside onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
switch(item.getId()){
   case android.R.id.home:
   FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
   fm.popBackStack ("frag1", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
   return true;
}
```

You can remove a fragment from the back stack

You can also alter the icon by setting a different resource inside your onCreate!

**UPDATE**

Since a fragment always lives inside an Activity, you wouldn't have to change a thing in your fragment but if you want a fragment to have more menu items like on the right hand side, you can enable optionsMenu inside onCreate() like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
```

From here, you can do as you would normally do in your activity!

I hope this helps!

Comment: How do I make the up navigation button appear in a fragment instead of in an activity.

Comment: How would I pop the backstack? @Eenvincible

Comment: It says that fm.popBackStack(String frag, int i) is an unreachable statement. @Eenvincible

Comment: You should move that code inside the case statement; I will update that for you

Comment: Actually this is causing the unreachable statement: mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); @Eenvincible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116936/discussion-between-eenvincible-and-tom-finet).

Comment: since you are inside the activity, just try calling `this.getSupportFragmentManager(); Seems we should continue this in a chat room

Comment: If I wanted to give a fragment its own toolbar with its own menu actions, different from those in the activity toolbar how would I do this? Should I create and inflate a new menu.xml file from the fragment or should I dynamically modify the activity action bar

Comment: Create menu xml for that fragment and using the code I show above, setHasOptionsMenu(true) like I did; that will show that menu in the fragment. Remember to inflate the xml like you would do in your activity

Comment: You have really helped me out! Thanks, ive got a lot to learn.